# Selection sort setting value in each loop

Tags: ruby, selection-sort

I am trying to find the smallest element in an array.

I tried to do this with `finding_smallest` method as follows:

```
def finding_smallest arr_arg
  # first time returns 3;
  # second time returns 3 again, even though arr_arg doesn't have it.
  p arr_arg    
  arr_arg.each do |el|
    if el < @min
      @min = el
    end
  end
  @min
end

def selection_sort array
  counter = 0
  sorting = ->(arr){
    arr_range = arr[counter..-1]
    smallest = finding_smallest(arr_range)
    p arr_range # first iteration - whole array; second iteration - [1..end of the array]
    p smallest # first iteration: 3, second iteration: 3;
    first_element_in_range = arr_range[0] # for switching indexes of smallest and first in array
    arr_range[arr_range.index(smallest)], arr_range[0] = arr_range[0], arr_range[arr_range.index(smallest)] #switching places
    counter += 1
    sorting.call(arr_range) unless counter == array.length || arr.nil?
  }
  sorting.call(array)
end

@array = [78, 42, 51, 49, 74, 53, 66, 39, 40, 3, 66, 100]
@min = @array[0]
selection_sort(@array)
```

It returns the smallest element from a previous array. I think the problem is that the `each` loop doesn't set the value for the second time (or first). What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@min` plays [here] a role of global variable (`main`’s instance variable.) Once set, it is never updated, since the minimum would never be touched anymore.

You might want to update it’s value on each subsequent call:

```
def finding_smallest arr_arg
  @min = arr_arg.first

  arr_arg.each do |el|
    if el < @min
      @min = el
    end
  end
  @min
end
```

In ruby we use [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) for that:

```
def finding_smallest arr_arg
  @min = arr_arg.reduce do |min, el|
    el < min ? el : min
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you need `@min` at all?

Comment: @Stefan I don’t but since the original implementation returned a value, stored in instance variable, I decided to decrease an impact of my changes.